# EventSource Polyfill

Tags: javascript, servicestack, ecmascript-6, eventsource

I have created a self-hosted ServiceStack service that runs in a Windows service based on their [showcase chat application](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat).

However, where I am not getting further is trying to write the client as a JavaScript (using the Aurelia skeleton) app as opposed to a ServiceStack.Razor application.

I have added the [EventSource](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) polyfill to my application. However, when I import eventsource into my js file where I want use the eventsource library I get the following exception:

> ERROR [app-router] Error: Unable to get property 'XMLHttpRequest' of undefined or null reference
>
> Error loading http://localhost:9000/dist/chats.js

It is failing on the following line in eventsource.js:

> var XHR = global.XMLHttpRequest;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, having had some communication with the creator of ServiceStack I have added a reference to ss-utils (which in turn uses eventsource.js). This has rectified the problem.

Comment: For EventSource polyfill I recommend to use Bundler https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bundler and bundle a version for ie and another for browsers which support EventSource